# Point snapping distance

Tags: point, distance, snapping

I have question -i need very easy shift 1 point. It is very difficult in new version. 
1.Why I can't shift point closer like red distance? Between red and yellow is not possible snapp. Blue is what I need. I had try change snapping options tolerance, radius...but same result. Version is 3.12.

2. why I cant shift point with left mouse continually? I need click and release buttton -shift and then click again.Terrible. In old version I could easy chatch point and move, here not.
   I upload short video here, you can look:
   https://uloz.to/file/N2X3kSbKYzi0/20200408-104927-mp4

I dont know why yesterday closed my question regarding this?It is very serious problem for all I think. If not solve i need go back to old Qgis. Because It is very comfortable I need catch and shift every point excatly where i need every milimeter.
Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMnL3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: Also, please add your settings for the snapping tool.

Comment: I had try all combination off settings - snaping by default, snapping tolerance up to zero, search radius.....  Software version and snapping options are  here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ1uE.jpg

Comment: Any solution pls?

Comment: Probably nobody is working with vectors.

Comment: Nobody is working with vectors in Qgis?
Hard to edit, hard to shift with mouse, snap point...terrible. I need go back to QGis 2.14